# Survey and forms - Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: survey

Sorry for my English, i'm french users.

It's possible to create a forme or Survey with insert table ?

Currently I use the poll application , creating top issues down , is it possible to purchase or download an application that allows me to include a table to be completed in order to make my survey .... ??? see the image  . A survey to know the information of the goods receipt.

Because if I take the survey is included in Sharepoint , I can only add questions , one after the other.

Thanks for your help[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Info-path designer** to create form like you attached.  Connect field of that form to the SharePoint list.  You can use the **SharePoint List** or **SharePoint Form Library** template for the same.